# How do I accept an answer, and is there a window in which to do so?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, asking-questions

I found a question whose answer was so exactly like what I have been searching for, but I need little clarification and a some more details. And what I really need is to restate the answer back again to see if I understand correctly. Is this allowed, and how would I do it?

Also, being quite new, how do I accept an answer? I can't find an option or button to click. Have I waited too long? I may have even accepted it already, I really don't remember!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Without a link to the question you mentioned and a little more detail it is hard to know how to answer the other half of your question. I would suggest that you go ahead and ask it if necessary we will close it or help you refine it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a problem many people have.  Below on the left you will see an answer that has not been accepted.  On the right is one that has.  Only the original author of the question sees the version on the left since only the author may select it -- thus you must be logged in.

[image]

To accept an answer, click on the checkmark. You may untick, or select a different answer, later, but there can only be one per question.

Also notice the up/down vote arrows.  Both these questions have been upvoted by me, so I see the up arrow as red.  You need 15 rep to vote up but 125 to vote down.  This applies to any question and any answer.

For more information about how the site works take [the tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) (which very clearly illustrates the use of the checkmark) and browse [the help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).  Both of these are easily accessible via the "help" menu on the right side of the top bar.